# Is this a valid statement according to the de Finetti theorem?

Tags: bayesian, random-variable, exchangeability, permutation

Some background on my problem - Let us consider a discrete memoryless channel (DMC) $W_{Y|X}$ from Alice to Bob. A DMC is a conditional probability distribution over the random variable $Y$ given input random variable $X$. We wish to send a uniformly randomly chosen message from a set of size $\mathcal{M}$ over this channel with average transmission error at most $\varepsilon$. To achieve this, one has an encoder on Alice's side that takes the message as input and outputs a random variable $X$. $X$ is the input to the channel which outputs random variable $Y$. A decoder on Bob's side takes random variable $Y$ as input and outputs a message. A transmission error has occurred in the communication protocol if the input and output messages are different and otherwise, Alice and Bob have successfully sent a message using $W$.

Now consider $n$ i.i.d. copies of the given DMC and denote it by $W_{Y|X}^{\otimes n}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. We ask what the maximum communication rate can be using the DMC $W_{Y|X}^{\otimes n}$. As before, we have an encoder that takes a uniformly random message from a set $\mathcal{M(n)}$ and outputs and $n$-bit string $X^n$. Let $p_{X^n}$ be the distribution over the $n$-bit strings $X^n$ when we encode a uniformly random message. $p_{X^n}$ must be invariant under any permutation of the $n$ positions since we have $n$ i.i.d. copies of the same channel. As we increase $n$, we add more i.i.d. copies of $W_{Y|X}$. Hence, the permutation invariance of our capacity-achieving $p_{X^n}$ holds for any choice of $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let us consider i.i.d. distributions $q_{X^k}^i = \prod\limits_{j=1}^kq^i_{X_j}$ for any choice of distribution $q^i$. Does there always exist a convex combination of such i.i.d. distributions such that

$$p_{X^k} = \sum_{i}\mu(i)q_{X^k}^i$$

where $\mu(i)$ is some measure that assigns a weight to each element of our convex combination. I am not sure if this claim is a special case of the de Finetti theorem (see Theorem 2 of [these notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture1.pdf)).

The point that I am confused about is whether my $p_{X^k}$ can be thought of as extendible for $n>k$ to allow me to invoke the de Finetti theorem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "permutation invariant ... strings"?  The only way the string itself can be permutation invariant is if all the values in the string are the same.  The exchangeability assumption in de Finetti's theorem is about permutation invariance of the *probabilities* of the strings.

Comment: @Ben, you are right, that is what I meant. For example, if we consider $3$ bit strings, I have that $p_{x_1x_2x_3} = p_{x_1x_3x_2} = p_{x_2x_1x_3} = p_{x_2x_3x_1} = p_{x_3x_2x_1} = p_{x_3x_1x_2}$.

Comment: Your revisions to this question introduce a number of objects and concepts that you have not defined, or have defined in an unusual way; please clarify.

Comment: Sorry about that @Ben, I have clarified. Is there any terminology that remains confusing? If yes, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: The difficulty with your question is this: you are asking whether you can extend to $n>k$ to get exchangeability for de Finetti's theorem, but you've already assumed that exchangeability holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (so the answer is trivially yes).  Your revisions have introduced a huge mess of extraneous probability concepts and notation that are hard to understand, not referenced, etc., all of which serves only to distract from a simpler question that is buried in there somewhere.  In its present state, the question is not clear and it is unlikely to attract answers.